# GLSL variable turns object black

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I currently have this vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void){
surfaceNormal = normal;
toLightVector = vec3(1, 100, 1);
gl_Position = ftransform(); #Yes, I use the fixed-function pipeline. Please don't kill me.
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

This works fine, but then when I add this:

```
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void){
vec3 pos = position; #Completely USELESS added line
surfaceNormal = normal;
toLightVector = vec3(1, 100, 1);
gl_Position = ftransform();
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

The whole object just turns black (Or green sometimes, but you get the idea - It isn't working).

Expected behaviour:
[image]
Actual behaviour:
[image]
(The terrain and water are rendered without any shaders, hence why they are not changed)

It's as if the variable "position" is poisonous - If I use it anywhere, even for something useless, my shader simply does not work correctly.

Why could this be happening, and how could I fix it?

Comment: what does the compilation/linking info log say?

Comment: At a guess I'd say that line happens to alter the attribute location of `textureCoords`. I'd double check you're not hard coding it.

Comment: @jozxyqk It still works with the "position" variable at the top - Just not when I use it in my code. I don't use any hard coding. As for rachet's question, I'm just trying to find it right now.

Comment: If by "at the top" you mean keeping the declaration and removing only the "#Completely USELESS added line" -> the compiler will remove the attribute "position" completely if it is not used. In this case the attribute locations MAY turn out the same as in your initial example and it works by chance. However, if you do not specify attribute locations, e.g. with the "layout(location = <number>)" qualifier, they can legally be assigned randomly by the compiler. So try adding location qualifiers or updating your locations with glGetAttribLocation... (the latter is slow if performed too often)

Comment: @Thomas http://gyazo.com/924d156e71bc94faed01fe1d829eae23 and http://gyazo.com/8b6ec63adcfa2339c208d830632bc4b5 are my current code - Are you suggesting I replace "0, 1, 2" with glGetAttribLocation(location) (and the same with textureCoords and normals)?

Comment: No. I just wasn't sure that you do bind your attribute locations explicitly, since that code wasn't shown. There is another method of specifying locations directly within the shader by `layout(location = 2) vec3 position` or similar. If you had not done it in your code the locations would have been arbitrarily chosen and it might have worked only by accident in the fist place. But as you have it, it looks okay. Also, make sure calling glBindAttribLocation before linking the shader. If you have not done so, check all shader logs / glGetError. Use a debugger like gDebugger to see your bindings.

Comment: @Thomas I am definitely binding the attributes: http://gyazo.com/27419a35601437b8812a5636fb9b6bcb

Comment: @ratchetfreak I cannot find any compiling or linking logs. I've looked eveywhere and even exited my game as soon as the shaders compile, but there's nothing.

Comment: @Joehot200 after compilation call [glGetShaderInfoLog](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) and after linking call [glGetProgramInfoLog](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml) and check what gets put in the `GLChar* infoLog` buffer

Comment: I suspect that you run into trouble because you use both the fixed function position (implied by the use of `ftransform`), and also a generic attribute for the position, which is bound to location 0. I haven't looked up the details on how exactly these two interact, but it looks very iffy.

Comment: @ratchetfreak The output is completely blank when I try and print it out - It's just am empty line. :( `System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(500, 500));`

Comment: @RetoKoradi You're possibly right, but what confuses me is why the "textureCoords" and "normal" variables work. Why is it specifically this one that's deciding to be an issue? My problem is that I have so much pre-existing code, that converting this all off of the fixed-function pipeline would be a lot of work.

Comment: From what I remember, the fixed function position is aliased to attribute location 0. Try using a location other than 0 for your `position` attribute. Or maybe don't specify the location, and use `glGetAttribLocation()` after you link instead. This way, you're sure that your generic attributes don't collide with fixed function attributes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi This appears to have fixed my problem! The variable is no longer "poisonous", and I can use it in my game with the expected results. I will do some more testing (and actually implement what I was trying to do in the first place) and then post an answer on what was wrong.

Comment: I can post an answer later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into problems because you use both the fixed function position attribute in your vertex shader, and a generic attribute bound to location 0. This is not valid.

While you're not using the fixed function `gl_Vertex` attribute explicitly, the usage is implied here:

```
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

This line is mostly equivalent to this, with some additional precision guarantees:

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

But then you are also using a generic attribute for the position:

```
in vec3 position;
...
vec3 pos = position;
```

If you assign location 0 for this generic attribute, the result is an invalid shader program. I found the following on page 94 of the OpenGL 3.3 Compatibility Profile spec, in section "2.14.3 Vertex Attributes":

> LinkProgram will also fail if the vertex shaders used in the program object contain assignments (not removed during pre-processing) to an attribute variable bound to generic attribute zero and to the conventional vertex position (gl_Vertex).

To avoid this problem, the ideal approach is of course to move away from using fixed function attributes, and adopt the OpenGL Core Profile. If that is outside the scope of the work you can tackle, you need to at least avoid assigning location 0 to any of your generic vertex attributes. You can either:

- Use a location > 0 for all attributes when you set the location of the generic attributes with `glBindAttribLocation()`.
- Do not set the location at all, and use `glGetAttribLocation()` to get the automatically assigned locations after you link the program.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to accept this, and only noticed when I went through my old questions. The answer worked for me. Thank you.